# How do I pass compressed data using the Task Queue Python API in App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, zlib, task-queue

I'm trying to use compressed data with my Tasks in the Task Queue like so:

```
t = taskqueue.Task(url='/tasks/queue',
                   params={'param': zlib.compress(some_string)}
```

However when I try to decompress it in the queue handler like so

```
message = self.request.get('param')
message = zlib.decompress(message)
```

I get this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u06b8' in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)

Anyone know of what's going on here? Is there a work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using params, use payload, which includes your data in the body of the request, unencoded. Then you can use `zlib.decompress(self.request.body)` to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2):

Read [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/tasks.html)... (my emphasis!):

> params Dictionary of parameters to use
>   for this Task. Values in the
>   dictionary may be iterable to indicate
>   repeated parameters. May not be
>   specified for a POST request if
>   payload is already specified. For POST
>   requests, these params will be encoded
>   as 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
>   and set to the payload; for all other
>   methods, the **parameters will be
>   converted to a query string**. May not
>   be specified if the URL already
>   contains a query string and the method
>   is GET.

`zlib.compress` produces an arbitrary string of bytes... but then query-string conversion interprets it as Unicode!  So, use any 1-byte codec, such as `latin-1`, to `.encode` the compressed results in order to pass (what's actually a binary) bytestring of params, and the same codec for a `.decode` to get back from the "unicode" string to a string of bytes that you can `decompress`.  Phew... you *sure* the compression is crucial enough to your app's performance to be worth this weird set of gyrations, or wouldn't it be better to eschew it?-)

Comment: Thanks, Alex!

I'm basically passing a fetched chunk of html to a handler to parse and process. I have to use compression to keep the Task object under 10KB. I guess I could store the HTML in the Datastore and then pass a key to the handler instead, but that seems wasteful of quota for now.